# android application issues with TCP server

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple android application that have several layouts that are supposed to be connected to the TCP Server. It works for the main page, but not other pages. Can someone tell me where the problem lies?

Below are my source code

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 2222;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "172.18.123.176";
    SeekBar seekbar;
    TextView value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        //


        value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
         seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);





        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
           boolean fromUser)
        {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              value.setText("SeekBar value is "+progress);
                                                        }

             public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                        }

          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                        }
        });


        //

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }



    public void onClick1(View view) {
        try {
            TextView et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick2(View view) {
        try {
            TextView et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }





    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="116dp"
    android:onClick="onClick1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="146dp"
    android:layout_y="134dp"
    android:text="LIGHT ON" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="190dp"
    android:onClick="onClick2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="146dp"
    android:layout_y="210dp"
    android:text="LIGHT OFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:layout_x="43dp"
    android:layout_y="350dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Living Room Light"
    android:textColor="#0b84aa"
    android:textSize="25dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="12dp"
    android:layout_y="87dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="205dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="70dp"
    android:layout_y="59dp"
    android:max="100" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean under "but not other pages"?

Comment: Are you getting any messages (errors, exceptions, etc..) ?

Comment: i mean second layout after pressing button. @MaximShoustin

Comment: Nope. Application crashes whenever I press the buttons on the 2nd layout. @Bishan

Comment: If your application crashed, there should be an error. see your logcat after crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you didn't post log trace, anyways, from your code I don't see you initiated `ClientThread` therefore your `socket` is `null` therefore any button press causes to crash.

add to the end of `Create`:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
```

Comment: How do I go about initiating `ClientThread`? Any examples to share?